# How to publish external apk plugin (jar) to Google Play Store?

Tags: android, plugins, jar, google-play, dexclassloader

I'm going to create an Android application (apk) which uploads and execute additional jar-packaged dex bytecode runtime via DexClassLoader. According to Google Play's policy (https://play.google.com/intl/en_ALL/about/privacy-security/malicious-behavior/) "Likewise, an app may not download executable code (e.g. dex, JAR, .so files) from a source other than Google Play."
As I understand, APK Expansion Files is not suitable for this architecture because it's possible to have only two ("main" and "patch") expansion files.

How to publish multiple external jar's (runtime plugins) with dex bytecode inside to Google Play Store?
What is the best practice for plugin extensible Android applications?

Comment: you can't publish a Jar to the google play. Some apps can download modules as the standalone APKs separately published in google play

Comment: Vlad, thanks for you answer! Could you explain me an idea of separately published plugin APKs? Does plugin should be standalone APK wich contains jar inside and copy it into some shared storage accessable from main application APK?